# mysql 1205 error on bulk delete in django admin

Tags: mysql, django, django-admin, innodb

I've moved to mysql from sqlite and funny issue - whenever I mass-delete objects via django admin (about 100 or so) I get this mysql error:

```
(1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

this has never happened with sqlite with the same models.

I am able to delete a max of two records, three are failing.

The setup is windows7, mysql 5.5.20, python 2.7, django 1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is directly from MySQL. It happens when there's a lock created on the table and it isn't released for whatever reason. You can try restarting your MySQL server. That might be enough to clear things up and allow you to proceed. You can also edit your `my.conf` file (not sure of its location in Windows, but should be with the rest of your MySQL stuff) and change the following line to a longer time period (number is seconds):

```
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there may be many causes to this issue. My case was caused by indexes mixing up somehow - I was only able to fix this by recreating the database and importing data.

in general

```
show status
show engine innodb status
explain <select causing issues>
```

may give some hints.